# Stop child process when parent process stops

Tags: android, events, process, runtime

In my android application, I create a child process with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

But may be a situation, where a user kills my application, but the child process is still running.  What I want is, when I kill the application, also kill the child process. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would

- Keep track of the processes created by my application.
- register a shutdown hook with the JVM through [`Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) that would be called when the application is shutdown and kill all the processes spawned, that were tracked in previous step.

Comment: **Vikdor**, I'm probably not quite true saying.  
I mean "kill" is stop from task manager. At first, I test in win7 in java: create simple application with infinite loop. Later stopped by: `taskkill /IM javaw.exe /f` and do not see, that hook thread is started

Comment: I have the same problem as the original question and tried using a shutdown hook - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173387/android-child-process-logcat-keeps-running-after-parent-process-app-died - but that didn't work. Any other idea?