# Android: Child process (logcat) keeps running after parent process (app) died

Tags: android, process, logcat

our Android app spawns a logcat shell process and then reads its result for processing.
However, when the app stops (e.g. when restarted after recompilation during development), the logcat process will keep running. Here's an example of this behaviour:

```
processes = new ArrayList<Process>();

try {
  processes.add(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time"));
  processes.add(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time"));
  processes.add(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time"));
  processes.add(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  // oh no!
}

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    for (Process p : processes) {
      p.destroy();
    }
  };
});
```

Add this to the onCreate() method of a test app, start it, then force-stop it using the settings manager. The child processes will keep running, now with a parent-id of 1.

In [How to kill logcat process initiated by Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940827/how-to-kill-logcat-process-initiated-by-android-application) it was suggested to use ProcessBuilder, but that wasn't a solution and the process will keep running, too.

In [Stop child process when parent process stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243415/stop-child-process-when-parent-process-stops) it was suggsted to use a shutdown hook - that doesn't work either as demonstrated above.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try calling p.waitFor() after p.destroy()? The former call waits for the child process to terminate and gets the return status, before proceeding to destroy the next one.

Comment: @Vikdor Thanks, but nope, doesn't work. In fact, adding a logging call in the shutdown hook reveals that it doesn't get called at all when the application (force-) stops.

Comment: I guess the copy of `processes` in the `new Thread()` is empty. Did you log from the `for` loop or from outside the loop? Can you mark processes as volatile so that threads won't cache the copy, and then check?

Comment: I logged before the for loop, the run() of the shutdown hook never gets called.

Answer (score 2):

What you *could* do is spwaning another script of which the sole purpose is to watch your Java program. Whenever it dies, kill all of its children too.

A fragile example:

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
String script = "while [ -d /proc/" + pid + " ];do sleep 1;done; killall logcat";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh", "-c", script);
```

This assumes that your process does not run as root, thereby only killing its own logcat processes. In your shutdown function, you should first kill the other processes (`logcat`) and then run `p.destroy();` to stop this killer script.

The script above can be improved by removing the use of `killall`. Instead, get the process IDs of your `logcat` processes using Reflection ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578924/427545) points to http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid) and pass them to `kill`.